# How to convert decibel values into positive values?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, math, signal-processing

I'm getting the decibel values in negative. I just want to plot these values on a graph ranging from 0 to 100. So is there any way to convert the decibel values into positive values?

Comment: You can remove the accept from my answer?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Just use fabs() C++ method

> fabs function 
>        double fabs (      double x );
>         float fabs (       float x ); long double fabs ( long double x );
>   Compute absolute value
>
> Returns the absolute value of x ( /x/
>   ).
>
> In C++, abs is also declared in this
>   header with the same behavior.
>
> Parameters x Floating point value.
>
> Return Value The absolute value of x.
>
> Portability In C, only the double
>   version of this function exists with
>   this name.

[fabs reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/fabs/)

Comment: That will make the value positive, but it will not be in the correct position relative to other points on the graph.

Comment: "So is there any way to convert the decibel values into positive values?" This is the question, and my answer is what he was looking for.

Comment: I did not downvote you. You are certainly correct in that your solution answers his question. Have an upvote :)

Comment: -1: It doesn't really answer the question, as using `abs` will *invert* the resulting graph (or worse, if there are both positive and negative dB values), which is almost certainly **not** what the OP wants.

Comment: I agree with Paul R and the anonymous downvoter.  My down vote is virtual, however, since strictly speaking the question has been answered although the answer is only marginally more useful than setting all the values to 1.0.

Comment: Again the men just asked how to convert from decimal in to positive values!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Terente: it should be fairly obvious from the question that the OP needs to shift and/or scale his values into the required range. Suggesting that he use `abs()` is not helpful.

Comment: hey, he gave me the correct answer what I was looking for. And also I've made some modifications to get the appropriate positive decibel values.

Answer (score 6):

It's quite common for `0 dB` to correspond to full scale input (remember that a plain dB scale actually defines a *ratio*, not an absolute value, so the meaning of `0 dB` is somewhat arbitrary). For e.g. 16 bit audio, values might typically range from `0 dB` to `-96 dB`. To represent this on a scale of `0 - 100` you could just add `96 dB` to bring this range up to `0..+96 dB`.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a solution specific to decibels, but if you want your scale to be from 0-100, take your minimum value (lets call it `minVal`), and add `-minVal` to get 0. Then divide it by your maximum value, and multiply by 100.

Comment: When you do the division, make sure the maximum value is the one you get *after* adding `-minval` to it.